# If I don’t use a static site generator on CloudFlare Pages, does each deploy still count towards the build limit?

Tags: github, cloudflare, static-site, cloudflare-pages

If I have a GitHub repository with static HTML, CSS, JavaScript, and some image files, and I publish this to CloudFlare Pages (and use no site generator), does it count towards the 500 builds per month limit?

Answer (score 0):

I think it does - below is one of my Pages project without a build step (connected to GitHub repo, not via direct upload)

[image]

And it seems that it still takes 1 second of time to 'build', and I think that count towards the build quota.